# silent renew in oidc-client-js does not work

Tags: angular, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am using oidc-client-js library to work with IdentityServer3, it works perfect but I cannot set up automatic “silent token renew” each time when oidc-client-js tries to renew token I get error in console

> Refused to display
>   'https://identity.blablabla.com/core/connect/authorize?client_id=...'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I used for test angular2 application from oidc github, there is screenshot of error in that moment when application tried renew token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZyos.png)

I understand that it is part of security of identity server to prevent open its pages in iframe, but in this case oidc-client-js cannot make silent token renew with **IdentityServer3**.
Probably someone had experience with this problem and can help to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was solved by putting silentRenewUrl to identity server configuration. There is [the solution](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/53)